# when the two matrices are Similar?

Tags: jordan-normal-form, similar-matrices

Let $a,b,c,d,e,f$ be complex numbers. Determine when the complex matrices,
\begin{align*}
    A= \begin{pmatrix}
    2& 1& b& c\\
    0& 2& d& e\\
    0& 0& 2& f\\
    0& 0& 0& 3\\
    \end{pmatrix} \qquad B= \begin{pmatrix}
    2& 1& 0& 0\\
    0& 2& -1& 0\\
    0& 0& 2& 1\\
    0& 0& 0& 3\\
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
are similar. Here $A$ and $B$ are said to be similar if there exist an invertible complex matrix $P$ satisfying $P^{-1}AP=B$.
I know that the similar matrices share some same properties. Same determinant, same trace, same eigenvalues, same char. polynomial etc. But in this case, I cannot get a relation between these complex numbers from those properties. So how do we enter the problem?
Idea please.

Comment: Think about the G.M of eigenvalue $2$

Comment: @Alearner: What is G.M? General Motors?

Comment: @JCAA sorry for the short, it's geometric multiplicity:)

Comment: The matrix $B$ has $2$ Jordan blocks with eigenvalue $2$ (sizes $2$ and $1$) and one Jordan block with eigenvalue $3$ of size $1$. The matrix $A$ also has eigenvalue $3$ of multiplicity $1$. So you need to look for Jordan blocks with eigenvalue $2$. To be similar to $B$ it must have a block of size $2$ and a block of size $1$.

Comment: @JCAA no, block of eigenvalue $2$ should be size of $3$ with only one block.

Comment: @Alearner: Look at $B$: it has $1,-1,1$ along the second diagonal, so its 2-blocks are of size $2$ and $1$.

Comment: @JCAA G.M of $2$ is $1$, the possibility of number of block corresponding to $2$ is $1$ ,and as , Algebraic multiplicity of $2$ is $3$ , so, size of the block corresponding to $2$ must be $3$

Comment: @Alearner: The geometric multiplicity of $2$ in $B$ is $2$ (I actually also thought it is $1$ but then I look at the OP again; perhaps it was edited).

Comment: @JCAA please notice, $(B-2I)^{2}\neq 0 $ but $(B-2I)^{3}=0$

Comment: @Alearner: OK, you are right.

Comment: I got the idea from the above conversation, to answer this problem the recipe is, first we have to find the generalized eigenvector for $\lambda = 2$ and the eigenvector for $\lambda=3$ then we can construct the matrix $P$?

Comment: How do we deal with $=-1$ in $B$